# List video files in a specific order in explorer - Windows 7

Tags: java, metadata, explorer, autoit

This is driving me to my wits-end, so here we go:

I have developed a script of sorts, where at one point, I am using AutoIt to drag a specific selection of video files into a third party application. These files MUST be listed in a specific order in the explorer window, so that when they are imported into the third party application, they are imported in that SAME order (the script keeps going at this point, and it is critical that this order is preserved).

I have tried renaming the files 0 - 9 (in the order I want) and sorting by file name... although this works, the files must have their original names when they are imported; explorer (along with every single replacement I have tried) reorders them once they are renamed back, ruining the whole process. I **cannot** figure out how to disable this auto-sorting in explorer or any other file manager (after *renaming* specifically).

The obvious next trial would be to add properties or tags of some sort to the files, and then sort by the chosen property/tag, however it seems programmatically impossible to accomplish this simple task from Java, AutoIt  or vbscript...

***In Summary:*** I have a number of video files which are automatically dragged from an explorer window to a third party application; the order that they appear in the explorer window (before being dragged over) is **crucial**, and they MUST have their proper file names when they are dragged over; How can I have them listed in explorer in a custom (user defined) order?

EDIT: I forgot one key part to this:

- The file paths are tied into this third party application.
- There are 1000s of other video files in this same folder

So the videos cannot be copied from another folder; they must come from this main folder in order to preserve referential integrity.

Comment: What about changing their creation date to one that will order them correctly, and then sorting the Explorer window by date?

Comment: That is an interesting idea... see the edit that I made; would I be able to filter out all the irrelevant video files (by - for example - setting a cutoff date)?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I like this idea. It might even be easier to open the files in the correct order and then sort by last access date. I don't know whether you can sort this way in explorer, but this data should be on an NTFS disk.

Comment: @Hassan that is actually what I was just thinking... you could just sequentially open them and close them in the script.

Would either of you gentleman know if it is possible to modify file details or tags programmatically? This would be the ideal solution, as it seems like the more proper way to accomplish this task.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but [here's a page](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-change-the-file-last-modified-date-in-java/) describing how it could be done with Java. You would probably want to change the date format so that the difference between the files' modification times could be in seconds instead of days.

Comment: And you could bypass the whole string-parsing part of the code altogether, and just create `Date`s that are within seconds of each other.

Comment: I won't add this as an answer, as I can't take credit for the idea of using timestamps, but AutoIt has a [FileSetTime](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileSetTime.htm) function which does exactly what you need in this case. I imagine the correct solution is reordering the items in the drag data, though I suspect that will be more complex than it's really worth.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the advice. @Matt: I am actually getting pretty comfortable with the windows API; would it be possible to *simulate* a drag and drop event into this third party application using an API call? I wouldn't mind going this route as a learning experience, and I know that Auto-IT can load and work with all the windows DLLs in the same basic way that vbs does....

Comment: @araisbec, you are welcome to try, but it's not simple WinApi  as it includes objects as well. [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776905(v=vs.85).asp)  is probably a good staring point.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply guys; I've been very busy lately with work. I am currently working on a DLL in visual studio which will *hopefully* allow me to automate a drag and drop event with whatever payload I desire to a specified third party application (and the coordinates for the "drop zone"). I am now going to post an answer to my question based off of my current work-around (thanks to a number of you guys), and then - if I am able to get this API-based solution working - I will reaccept with my "optimal" solution, explain it, and drop a link to the source code!

Answer (score 0):

How about getting a list of the filenames (in any order), then in your script reorder them in any required way, then passing that reordered list to the third-party app?

Comment: Unfortunately, the app does not work this way; the only way to import the video files to the "project timeline" is to drag them onto it (in the correct order), or to highlight them within the library of the app itself (which is closed source, and the library is massive).

That being said; I already have the ordered list of filenames in memory... would it be possible to *simulate* a drag and drop using the windows API? I've recently started coding a lot with this API, and it seems like this might be possible...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Hovercraft Full Of Eels and @Hassan for pointing me in the right direction for this!

The solution is a bit of a hack, but it works consistently and is simple to implement... it is based around manipulating the "Date Modified" property of the target files, and is good for scripts which you'd ideally like to run consecutive days without modifications:

**1. Pick a date far off in the future as your "Start Date"** (I used 2068) - You could alternatively pick tomorrow (as in the day after your current date) *as long as* the file manager you drag the files from allows you to specify "Today" as a filter date (ie. windows explorer). I ended up using Xplorer2, and this does not have a similar feature, so I picked a date which the script will never be run on.

**2. Change the "Date Modified" on your files so that the date is ordered in the same order you need your files; begin this on the Start Date** - Should be very simple in any scripting language; In AutoIT, I read in the original dates using FileGetTime(), stored them in an array (to reset later), and then used the function FileSetTime() to make the change.

**3. Filter the files using your Start Date, and sort them** - In windows explorer (Win 7) you can use "System.DateModified:>today" in the search bar, and then sort by date modified in the right click menu. In Xplorer, I was able to setup and save a Filter which filtered out all files modified the day before my Start Date or earlier.

**4. Reset the Date Modified property for your files** - If you are writing a script which will run multiple times, you will want to reset the dates you changed so that the these files do not appear along with your target files during a subsequent execution.

There you go! I am currently working on an alternative to this (using the Windows API for Drag-and-Drop), and if I manage to get it working I will post a new answer!